# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined :: javascript :: bing maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

so i am having problems with this displayinfobox function. I was looking into the Bing Maps v8 API trying to link up events with infobox. I am following Bing and storing event handlers in the infobox object. Im getting this read property 'add' error.

In in the stacktrace, it is taking me to either the line where i am adding an event handler, or when im checking if infobox has any events attached to it.

I am trying to follow this script here https://blueric.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/creating-hover-style-info-boxes-on-the-bing-maps-ajax-v7-0-control/. Given it is quite old, i would assume things might work in similar ways.

**Edited:**

It seems like it has something to do with addHandler which im confused on.

```
 function displayInfoBox(e) {

    stopInfoBoxTimer(e);

    console.log("after Infobox Timer");

    if (_displayInfoType != "INFOBOX")
        return;

    var replaceContent = infoboxTemplate;
    var ticket = e.target.ticket;
    var contentHead = "<ul>";
    var contentEnd = "</ul>";
    var content = "";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR} + "</li>";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR} + "</li>";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR} + "</li>";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR} + "</li>";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR}+ "</li>";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR}+ "</li>";
    content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR}+ "</li>";

    if (ticket.WW_PK != "")
        content += "<li><b>:</b> " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR}+ ", " + ticket.{REMOVED VAR}+ "</li>";
    else
        content += "<li><b>: <span  style='color:red;'>{REMOVED VAR}</span></b></li>";


    replaceContent = replaceContent.replace('{title}', ticket.{REMOVED VAR});
    replaceContent = replaceContent.replace('{content}', contentHead + content + contentEnd);

    console.log("after replaced content");
    var options = {
        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(23, 173),
        location: e.target.getLocation(),
        htmlContent: replaceContent,
        visible: true
    };

    console.log(options);

    console.log("before removing events from infobox");
    if (infobox != null && infobox.mouseLeaveHandler != null && infobox.mouseEnterHandler != null) {

        if (Microsoft.Maps.Events.hasHandler(infobox, 'mouseleave'))
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(infobox.mouseLeaveHandler);

        if (Microsoft.Maps.Events.hasHandler(infobox, 'mouseenter'))
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(infobox.mouseEnterHandler);

        infobox = null;
    }
    console.log("after removing events from infobox");
    console.log(infobox);
    infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(location, options);
//-------------------------- ERROR IN HERE ---------------------------------

    infobox.mouseLeaveHandler = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(infobox, 'mouseleave', infoBoxMouseLeave);
    infobox.mouseEnterHandler = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(infobox, 'mouseenter', infoBoxMouseEnter);
//-------------------------- ERROR IN HERE ---------------------------------
    console.log(infobox.mouseEnterHandler);
    infobox.setMap(map);
 }
```

**Edited (LATEST):** it seems like there is a bug with Bing V8 or just a change in the way this code is processed. I have copied most of the code into a fiddle project and it works fine in v7. So i am going to do this manually.

I will post working code once, this is completed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything with an `add` property in the posted code?

Comment: @adeneo - nor anything that calls `add`. I'm confused. Also, under ERROR IN HERE there is `infobox.setMap(map);` but `map` does not exist.

Comment: @adeneo It could be a bad argument by the OP that throws an error in the Microsoft code.

Comment: @adeneo yeah there isnt any `add` property list in my script at all, which is the confusing part. I have edited the post with the the desired effect i want.


@Vld yeah, thats the thing, im not calling anything with `add`


@gcampbell im thinking there is a bad arguement, but i have debugged the code for a while now and its not making sense. Cause i have basically copy pasted code from Microsoft to add events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Infobox class doesn't have mouseleave or mouseenter events. As such, when you try adding event handers for this, the "add" part of this step fails because these events don't exist.

Comment: Yep i posted an answer with that. But i will mark your as the answer. Would you happen to know how i can achieve that effect with v8??

Comment: Since you are using custom HTML for the infobox, you can use standard JavaScript events for this instead. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft disabled events on infoboxs in v8.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31fdf1ce-d0e2-47d2-9d34-5d722cccd291/why-are-infobox-events-not-needed-in-v8?forum=bingmapsajax